# How can I show boolen values (true and false) to user in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building an e-commerce site with react js and asp.net core web api. When adding a product in react, the biddable value of the product should be given by the person who added the product, and this value should be false by default. Its equivalent in the isOfferable database is kept as a bool value. So I want the user to select a value as false or true and when I say add product, it should be added to the products in the database, but I could not find how to keep the bool value in react.js.

**My AddProduct.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../../Css/AddProduct.css'

import { ProductAddSchema } from "../../validations/productAddSchema"
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import {useFormik} from 'formik'


function AddProduct() {

  //const [baseImage,setBaseImage] =useState("")

  //fetch data 
  const [colors, SetColors] = useState([])
  const [brands, SetBrands] = useState([])
  const [categories, SetCategories] = useState([])
  const [usedStatus, SetUsedStatus] = useState([])

 
  useEffect(() => {
    getAll()

  }, [])




  async function getAll() {

    //getall colors
    axios.get('http://localhost:64082/api/color/getall')
      .then(response => {
        SetColors(response.data)
      }).catch(error => {
        return alert("Error: " + error);
      })

    //getall brands
    axios.get('http://localhost:64082/api/brand/getall')
      .then(response => {
        SetBrands(response.data)
      }).catch(error => {
        return alert("Error: " + error);
      })


    //getall categories
    axios.get('http://localhost:64082/api/categories/getall')
      .then(response => {
        SetCategories(response.data)
      }).catch(error => {
        return alert("Error: " + error);
      })

    //getall usingstatus (new or used)
    axios.get('http://localhost:64082/api/usingstatus/getall')
      .then(response => {
        SetUsedStatus(response.data)
      }).catch(error => {
        return alert("Error: " + error);
      })


  }


  const { handleSubmit, handleChange, values, errors, touched } =
    useFormik({

      initialValues: {
        name: "",
        description: "",
        colorId: "",
        brandId: "",
        categoryId: "",
        price: "",
        isOfferable:false
       
      },
      onSubmit: (values) => {
        console.log(values);
        try {
          axios({
            method: "post",
            url: "http://localhost:64082/api/products/add",
            data: { values }

          });
          return alert("Success!");
        } catch (error) {
          return alert("Error: " + error);
        }

      },
      validationSchema: ProductAddSchema
    })



  
  return (

    <div className='space'>


      <div className="create">
        <h2>Add a New Product</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label>Product Name:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name='name'
            value={values.name}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="product name"
          />

          {errors.name && touched.name && (
            <div >{errors.name}</div>
          )}

          <label>Product Description:</label>
          <textarea
            value={values.description}
            onChange={handleChange}
            name="description"
            placeholder='description'
          ></textarea>

          {errors.description && touched.description && (
            <div >{errors.description}</div>
          )}

          <label>Product color name:</label>
          <select
            name='colorId'
            value={values.colorId}
            onChange={handleChange}>
            <option >select color</option>
            {
              colors?.map((color, index) => {

                return (<option key={index} value={color.colorId}>{color.name}</option>)
              })
            }
          </select>

          {errors.colorId && touched.colorId && (
            <div  >{errors.colorId}</div>
          )}



          <label>Product brand name:</label>
          <select
            name='brandId'
            value={values.brandId}
            onChange={handleChange}>
            <option >select brand</option>
            {
              brands?.map((brand, index) => {
                return (<option key={index} value={brand.brandId}>{brand.name}</option>)
              })
            }
          </select>

          {errors.brandId && touched.brandId && (
            <div >{errors.brandId}</div>
          )}

          <label>Product category name:</label>
          <select
            name='categoryId'
            value={values.categoryId}
            onChange={handleChange}>
            <option >select category</option>
            {
              categories?.map((category, index) => {
                return (<option key={index} value={category.categoryId}>{category.categoryName}</option>)
              })
            }
          </select>
          {errors.categoryId && touched.categoryId && (
            <div >{errors.categoryId}</div>
          )}

          <label>Product Price:</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            name='price'
            value={values.price}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="price TL"
          />
          {errors.price && touched.price && (
            <div >{errors.price}</div>
          )}



          <select
            name='usingStatusId'
            value={values.usingStatusId}
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            <option >select used state</option>
            {
              usedStatus.map((state, index) => {


                return (<option key={index} value={state.usingStatusId}>{state.usedStatus}</option>)
              })
            }
          </select>
          {errors.categoryId && touched.categoryId && (
            <div >{errors.categoryId}</div>
          )}



         <label>is Offerable:</label>
          <select
            name='isOfferable'
            value={values.isOfferable}
            onChange={handleChange}>
            
            <option></option>     {/*I tried to do it here but I couldn't*/}
            <option></option>

          
          </select>
          {errors.isOfferable && touched.isOfferable && (
            <div >{errors.isOfferable}</div>
          )} 


          <button type='submit' >Add Product</button>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddProduct;
```

Comment: "I could not find how to keep the bool value in react.js."  Can you explain what you mean by this?  Are you asking how to store values in your database?

Comment: @DanielBeck I think he means that he received 1 or 0 instead of true or false, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please read this to improve the quality of your question

Comment: I'm trying to get the user to select the isOfferable field which will return true or false. I tried to do this because the isOfferable field in the database is bool, but as an option, bool value is not returned, I guess only string value is returned.

Comment: Yes @NicolasMenettrier I mean it but as I said, bool value is not sent by using select and option, only string value comes from there.

Comment: @NewPartizal put 1 or 0 as value, it will be the same for your database. Did you search on stackoverflow before posting your question ?

Comment: Yes I searched but I asked because I wanted to do it this way. Of course, there are multiple alternatives to this.

Answer (score 0):

false, null, undefined, and true are valid children but. They simply don't render anything and are ignored in react. So if you want to render any of the above for example false you have to write an expression that will return a text representing the boolean example:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   const status = false;
   return (
        <div>
           <h1>The status is{String(status)}</h1>
        </div>  
)}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not very clear as the previous commenter writes.

However, the way to store a variable or piece of data in React is by using: `useState()` hook.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(false);
```